# DAX Distinct Strings looking in column of Lists

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to do a DISTINCT function with DAX, however looking within list values and not just the column value. Sample data (sorry for the formatting):

```
Name   Word List  
Bob   {aye, bee, cee}  
Bob   {aye, bee, cee}  
Jim   {dee, eee, eff}  
Jim   {dee, eee, eff}  
Ray   {aye, bee, cee}  
Ray   {dee, eeee, eff}
```

**Desired Measure Output**
Distinct Words for Jim: 3
Distinct Words for Bob: 3
Distinct Words for Ray: 6

Is there a way for the measure to look through the list and count distinct values?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question *how to count distinct in columns of lists* but is a workaround to get the desired results.

I would use the query editor and `Split Column > by delimiter` (under the Home tab) and `Replace Values` (under the transform tab) to get your table to look something like this:

```
Name   1    2   3
Bob    aye  bee cee
Bob    aye  bee cee
Jim    dee  eee eff
Jim    dee  eee eff
Ray    aye  bee cee
Ray    dee  eeee eff
```

After that I would select all columns except `Name` and use `Unpivot Columns`, which would make your table look like this (after removing the `Attribute` column).

```
Name    Word
Bob aye
Bob bee
Bob cee
Bob aye
Bob bee
Bob cee
Jim dee
Jim eee
Jim eff
Jim dee
Jim eee
Jim eff
Ray aye
Ray bee
Ray cee
Ray dee
Ray eeee
Ray eff
```

By simply dragging the `Name` and `Word` columns into a Matrix visual now you would get distinct count.

If you have a lot of data you could instead `Group By` on name with `Count Distinct Rows` as Operation already in the Query Editor and you would get a table that looks like your desired result.